# How to specify parameter for generic list type extension method in c#

Tags: c#, generics, parameters, extension-methods

I am trying to make an extension method that will shuffle the contents of a generic list collection regardless of its type however im not sure what to put in between the <..> as the parameter. do i put object? or Type? I would like to be able to use this on any List collection i have.

Thanks!

```
public static void Shuffle(this List<???????> source)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        int index = rnd.Next(0, source.Count);
        object o = source[0];

        source.RemoveAt(0);
        source.Insert(index, o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make it a generic method:

```
public static void Shuffle<T>(this List<T> source)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        int index = rnd.Next(0, source.Count);
        T o = source[0];

        source.RemoveAt(0);
        source.Insert(index, o);
    }
}
```

That will allow it to work with any `List<T>`.

Comment: I've got to learn to type faster. Anyway, `IList<T>` would be more general.

Comment: when i try all the methods listed i get...  Argument '2': cannot convert from 'object' to 'T'

Comment: @Grant: You need to change the portion in the middle to use "T" instead of "object" (or add a cast).  As John mentioned, using IList<T> would be more general, although not all IList<T> implement insertion, so it may not work generally.

Comment: `IList<T>` has the `Insert` method. What class implements `IList<T>` and does not implement `Insert`?

Comment: @John: Any implementation with ICollection<T>.IsReadOnly set to true often throws on insert.  I've had this bite me before.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cfatk9t.aspx

Comment: Personally, I agree that making this work on IList<T> is better, though... its just something I thought I'd mention, as one consideration.

Answer (score 4):

You just make your own method generic:

```
public static void Shuffle<T>(this List<T> source)
```

Answer (score 3):

Slightly off-topic, but a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) will have less bias and better performance than your method:

```
public static void ShuffleInPlace<T>(this IList<T> source)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    var rng = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        int j = rng.Next(i, source.Count);

        T temp = source[j];
        source[j] = source[i];
        source[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think this solution faster to process, because you will get your itens randomly and your collection position will be preserved to future use.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static T GetRandom<T>(this List<T> source)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int index = rnd.Next(0, source.Count);
            T o = source[index];
            return o;
        }
    }
}
```

Steps:

1. Create your Static Class to Identify your extensions
2. Create you Extension Method (must be static)
3. Process your data.